# Is it possible to block access to direct route?

Tags: kong

I am having an api under my kong. I added all routes using POST route (ex. under /myapi). How can I exclude someone of them ? Ex. I need to block acess to /myapi/somecontroller/somemethod. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Kong does not work over endpoints, just over apis.
Said that, your issue is a common desire when using an api gateway. I resolved in this way:

- In your main upstream api, group all your protected endpoints under an unique route `protected`:

> - /code/protected (protected access)
> - /code (public access)

- Add 2 apis to kong. One for the protected api and other for the public api.
- To the protected api add the plugin ACL with a whitelist with one a dedicated consumer. That consumer can represent to you or nobody.

I attach a resumed list of these 2 apis as a guide (Using Kong version 0.12).

Put attention over `uris`, `preserve_host` and `strip_uri`. Set strip_uri to true means that the api can be reached directly through `http://my-api.localhost` ie, /code is not part of the real route.

I include the plugin CORS for free ;)

```
// api public
$ prettycurl curl --url http://localhost:8001/apis/my-api
{
    "methods": [
        "GET",
        "POST",
    ],
    "name": "my-api",
    "preserve_host": false,
    "strip_uri": true,
    "upstream_url": "http://my-api.localhost",
    "uris": [
        "/code"
    ]
}
// api protected    
$ prettycurl curl --url http://localhost:8001/apis/my-api-protected
{
     "methods": [
        "GET",
        "POST",
    ],
    "name": "my-api-protected",
    "preserve_host": false,
    "strip_uri": true,
    "upstream_url": "http://my-api.localhost",
    "uris": [
        "/code/protected"
    ]
}

// api public plugins
$ prettycurl curl --url http://localhost:8001/apis/my-api/plugins
{
    "data": [
        {
            "config": {
                "credentials": false,
                "headers": [
                    "X-Requested-With",
                    "Authorization",
                    "X-api-key",
                    "Content-Type"
                ],
                "methods": [
                    "GET",
                    "POST",
                ],
                "origins": [
                    "http://localhost:3000"
                ],
                "preflight_continue": false
            },
            "enabled": true,
            "name": "cors"
        }
    ],
}

// api protected plugins
$ prettycurl curl --url http://localhost:8001/apis/my-api-protected/plugins
{
    "data": [
        {
            "config": {
                "whitelist": [
                    "admin"
                ]
            },
            "enabled": true,
            "name": "acl"
        },
        {
            "config": {
                "credentials": false,
                "headers": [
                    "X-Requested-With",
                    "Authorization",
                    "X-api-key",
                    "Content-Type"
                ],
                "methods": [
                    "GET",
                    "POST"
                ],
                "origins": [
                    "http://localhost:3000"
                ],
                "preflight_continue": false
            },
            "enabled": true,
            "name": "cors"
        }
    ]
}
```

Instead of ACL you could use any other Authentication plugin as Basic Auth or JWT, but ACL with a dummy consumer is the most quick workaround. I started with Kong just over a couple of weeks, so I hope this answer can helps. Probably the there is a better solution, but that is my best for the moment.